# Moore-Penrose generalized determinant

Tags: r, matrix-inverse

Is there a function in R to calculate the generalized determinant of a singular matrix? (similar to the `ginv()` used to compute the generalized inverse)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That determinant would be the product of [all singular values that you consider to be nonzero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Singular_value_decomposition_.28SVD.29), leading to this solution:

```
# The generalized determinant of x
det.mp <- function(x) {
     sigma <- zapsmall(svd(x)$d)   # The singular values of x
     prod(sigma[sigma != 0])       # Product of the nonzero singular values
}
```

Here is an application:

```
# Create test data
p <- 15                            # Number of columns
n <- 6                             # Number of rows
set.seed(17)
x <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), n, p)
x <- rbind(x, x[1,])               # Assure at least one singularity
det.mp(x)
```

The output is `3013.513`.  Note that `x` does not have to be a square matrix.

**In larger problems,** to avoid overflow you might need instead to obtain the *logarithm* of the determinant:

```
sum(log(sigma[sigma != 0]))
```

(This assumes all singular values are non-negative, because when `log` is applied to negative values it just returns NaN.  Negative values can be handled by the related but slightly more complicated solution

```
tau <-sigma[sigma != 0]
list(modulus=sum(log(abs(tau))), sign=prod(sign(tau)))
```

which returns the logarithm of the *magnitude* of the determinant along with the sign of the determinant, exactly as in the built-in function `determinant` with the "logarithm" option.)

Comment: The comparison to zero might require some testing. An alternative would be something like `abs(sigma) >= .Machine$double.eps`. The issue with `zapsmall()` is that it only sets very small numbers to 0 when there also is a big one. A hypothetical example: `a <- c(.Machine$double.eps / 10, .Machine$double.eps / 10); b <- zapsmall(a); b[b != 0]` gives both numbers that are numerically indistuingishable from zero.

Comment: Thank you for amplifying that point, caracal.  You are correct: `zapsmall` is there as a placeholder for *your* procedure to decide what numbers should be considered zeros.  In this case, `zapsmall` is a reasonable default solution: it zeros out any singular value that is very small compared to the larger singular values, which is usually what one wants to do.